# How do I change a bulb in flush mounted light fixture?

Tags: lighting

My bedroom has a very nice looking flush mounted ceiling light with a glass dome. However, the bulb has gone out and I cannot get the glass out to replace it. I have tried rotating the whole thing but it barely moves!! Is there another way I should be approaching this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some fixtures are "spring" loaded pulling straight down may release or let the cover be lowered enough to change the bulb.  If it is this type after changing the bulb push straight up and it will snap back in place.

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing it to one side (may take a few tries to figure out which side).